# Can not ping or access guest from host - vmware

Tags: networking, vmware, vmware-workstation

I have win7 OS with vmware workstation with debian 7. This is the ipconfig of host(win 7)

```
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.47.235.94
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0
```

I am connected by NAT (I could not manage to do bridged connection). ifconfig of the guest is this

[image: debian 7 ifconfig - vmware]

But pinging guest from host by ip `192.168.252.138` gives Request timed out. If I enable some network adapter from win7 network conenctions, say `VMnet1`, accordingly these lines appear in win7 ipconfig

```
Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4561:18cc:8abc:93a2%15
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.71.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

and I can ping host from guest by `192.168.71.1`, but again can not ping guest from host(this is what I need).

I do not have any firewall rules in guest: `/sbin/iptables -L` shows no rules.

I am able to create custom virtual network and connect guest to it setting static ip address, in that case I can connect from host to guest, but the problem is I can not connect to the internet from guest.

thanks

Answer (score 38, accepted):

instead of vmnet1 I had to enable `VMware Network Adapter VMnet8`, doing so it added the following to the host's config

```
Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::28e4:a65d:b520:ad92%16
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.252.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

after this I was able to ping the guest from host. The connection type between host and guest is nat.

**update**

if it is already enabled, disabling and re-enabling might help (thanks Paul G)

Comment: My VMNet8 was enabled and I still could not ping my Cent/OS guest. I had to disable it and re-enable it. Then it started working. Thanks for pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: @PaulG, np and thanks for the comment, i added that to the asnwer

Comment: For me even disable enable of VMNet8 didn't help. Somehow my VMNet adapters IPV4 settings got changed. So I had to edit the properties for VMNet1 and VMNet8 adapter and change IPV4 settings to DHCP. After that the connections from host to guest worked.

Comment: You save my night!

Comment: For some reason, selecting "NAT" as the virtual adapter didn't work, while selecting "Custom - VMNet8 - NAT" worked.  No idea why they would be different.

Comment: None of this worked for me. I can ping from the guest (Windows 7) to the host (MacOS Mojave). But pinging from the host to the guest still doesn't work.

Comment: I had the same issue and I was going crazy. Would you happen to have multiple VMs installed by any chance? I did. I had Virtual Box installed as well. I disabled the virtual adapter for it and voila! It worked!

Answer (score 5):

Just leaving this here should anyone run into this issue and not find a fix.

Its kind of obvious, but also make sure your guest, if running windows, is actually discoverable.

Type "HomeGroup" in start, and either change network location to private or go to "Change advanced sharing settings" and set permissions accordingly for public.

It is one of those small details that can be easy to overlook...

Answer (score 0):

### [Virtual Network Editor] sets ISO-OSI-Layer-1 & 2

.. providing a physical abstraction on physical media and a control layer of CSMA/CD for Ethernet-type LANs

**Your setup had**, on the same VMne1 CSMA/CD domain, **two disjunct Layer-3 network address definitions**:

```
W7 was an L2 CSMA/CD-VMnet1 connected [host] on an L3 [network]  10.47.235.94/32
W7 had an L2 CSMA/CD-VMnet1 setup            as an L3 [network] 192.168.71.0/24   #(*) 
VM was an L2 CSMA/CD-VMnet1 connected [host] on an L3 [network] 192.168.252.0/24
```

and, besides the obviously non-matching configuration (**^***), **there was no L3** [network] **interconnection** via a [**`router`**] to get the two discjunct worlds have an IP-route-able connection in between.

### This will never fly

Either setup a [**`router`**] role, or configure L3-"matching" addresses or move onto a separate VMnet ( and the VmWare will "route" for you )